# Mocha variable with Typescript TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

I've created two test files in **Typescript** for **Mocha** but when try to run it

```
mocha -r ts-node/register ./test/*.spec.ts
```

show this error

```
 error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'assert'.
```

**File test A** ( a.spec.ts ) contain the same declaration of **File test B** ( b.spec.ts ) an example

```
const assert = require('node:assert')
```

This is my Typescript config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",                                
    "module": "commonjs",                           
    "declaration": true,                             
    "declarationMap": true,                        
    "outDir": "./dist",                                 
    "esModuleInterop": true,                          
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,         
    "strict": true,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true                               
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "tests/**/*", "src/lib/*"]
}
```

This is devDependencies

```
 - "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1"  
 - "@types/node": "^17.0.35"
 - "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.26.0"
 - "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.26.0"
 -  "eslint": "^8.16.0"
 -  "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0"
 -  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0"
 -  "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.2.0"
 -  "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0"
 -  "mocha": "^10.0.0"
 -  "ts-node": "^10.8.0"
 -   "typescript": "^4.7.2"
```

Is possible with mocha created different files test but with same declaration ?

Comment: I **solved** with convert in `import assert from 'node:assert'`, but I don't know if is the better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
const assert = require('node:assert')
```

with

```
import assert from 'node:assert'
```